# Determine if element is selectable

Tags: javascript, selection, textselection

When selecting all the children of an element I sometimes receive the following error in Gecko/Waterfox:

> Error: NS_ERROR_FAILURE

This implies (in a very unhelpful fashion) that the element is (for some reason or another) *not* selectable. Here is an example of such code:

```
var e = document.getElementById('example');

if (e.childNodes.length > 0)
{
 window.getSelection().removeAllRanges();
 window.getSelection().selectAllChildren(e);
}
```

**How do I determine if an element is selectable?** Obviously, as the JavaScript implies, there are child elements in my tests implying that the element should be selectable. Absolutely no frameworks/libraries/etc.

Comment: does `var sel = window.getSelection(); if (sel.anchorNode) {...}` make a difference

Comment: Do you have an example that shows it failing?

Comment: @epascarello It's a lame Gecko bug, see the answer I posted below. Thank you for inquiring!

Answer (score 0):

There is cheap, affordable and expensive. The vast majority of times one should strive for an affordable answer. Unfortunately it appears that cheap is appropriate in this circumstance. Using 1 millisecond delay with `setTimeout` seems to have eliminated the issue.

```
var e = document.getElementById('example');

if (e.childNodes.length > 0)
{
 window.getSelection().removeAllRanges();
 setTimeout(function() {window.getSelection().selectAllChildren(e);},1);
}
```

This is clearly a **Gecko bug** on the internal timing mechanisms *however* after filing *dozens* of *quality* bug reports at Mozilla for over a decade that have fallen on deaf ears anyone encountering this issue will just have to waste a few more bytes until I take over Mozilla.

**Similar Bugs...**

The error message is very generic so to determine if the error has to do with the internal timing mechanisms of the JavaScript engine (that developers working with JavaScript should *never* have to be concerned with) it is *critical* to ensure that every mouse movement, click, etc is reproduced and in the same order. If it appears that the exact same actions sometimes fail without any predictability other than simply happening in non-deterministic fashion then using `setTimeout` *might* help alleviate such issues though ultimately it is a browser bug that *should* be fixed.